# Error upgrading Spring Boot 2.2.7 to Spring Boot 2.3.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was using `Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE` and everthing was working well.
When i upgraded to `Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE`, a few issues start to show up, i was able to resolve them except for this.

I have this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    public static final String PROPERTY_RESOLVING_CACHE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME = "propertyResolvingCacheResolver";

    @Value("${my.cache.name}")
    private String myCacheName;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(PROPERTY_RESOLVING_CACHE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new PropertyResolvingCacheResolver(cacheManager(), environment);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache(myCacheName))); 
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

and the error i am getting is this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'environment' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ShortcutDependencyDescriptor.resolveShortcut(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1238)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolvedCachedArgument(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.access$000(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

I thought it was an issue with the *'life-cycle'* of the beans, and i was auto-wiring too early, so i did this:

```
public class CacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport implements EnvironmentAware {
 ...
 private Environment environment;
 ...
    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
 ...
```

But then, other issues start showing(after doing the above) like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

This is getting out of my league, any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**Edit 1:**
After experimenting a bit, the issue is because the creation of this bean `@Bean(PROPERTY_RESOLVING_CACHE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)` is deferred to a later time.

It used to be created after `cacheManager`, but in `2.3.0.RELEASE`, it's not anymore.

**Edit 2:**
`DataSourceHealthIndicator` is in the application context under bean name `dbHealthContributor` for both `2.2.7.RELEASE` & `2.3.0.RELEASE`.

This can be seen under /actuator/beans :

```
 "dbHealthContributor": {
     "aliases": [],
     "scope": "singleton",
     "type": "org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator",
     "resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]",
     "dependencies": [
         "dataSource"
     ]
 },
```

Comment: Hey ! it seems that you have resolved your issue! ?

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram, yes, i posted what i did, in case you have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having `trace=true` in `application.properties`, i managed to pin-point the issue.

I used to have this working(provided *for free* by `Spring Boot`):

```
@Autowired
private DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator;
```

But it seems that `dataSourceHealthIndicator` 's creation has been *delayed* so that when my bean(that needs it) is being created, it couldn't find it and autowiring failed.

I therefore *created* it *manually*:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator(DataSource dataSource) {

    return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource, "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
}
```

and my error is gone.

> I hope to be able to understand what happened to
>   `dataSourceHealthIndicator` between `2.2.7.RELEASE` and
>   `2.3.0.RELEASE`. I do not see anything mention about it in the
>   [Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes)
>   or i have missed it, but i can still see it being "created" - see my **Edit 2** in my question.

Comment: can you autowire DataSourceHealthIndicator  at a method or constructor instead of autowiring at field level and see if that works?

Comment: @TechJunkie, thanks for the suggestion, worth a try, but unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration stays the same across the versions you mentioned; I think, DataSourceHealthIndicator bean still getting created by spring; if not, you would not require @Primary.

Comment: Hi @TechJunkie, it's confirmed that the bean is still being created under bean name `dbHealthContributor`, that's why i don't understand my issue. I am using @Primary as a precaution as at the end of the day, there are 2 beans of type `DataSourceHealthIndicator` i.e my bean and the `dbHealthContributor`

Comment: can you try with @Qualifier("dbHealthContributor")?

Comment: Hey @TechJunkie, that does not work, as `DataSourceHealthIndicator` is not there at that point in time. So, there is no qualifying bean.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, but I ran into the same problem when upgrading Spring Boot from 2.2.0 to 2.3.0. You could also solve the problem by using Spring's `@Lazy` annotation. That way the `DataSourceHealthIndicator` would be autowired later when it actually gets used and by that time the autoconfiguration would make it available for autowiring. And you wouldn't have to define your own bean like you did in your answer.

So instead of

```
@Autowired
private DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator;
```

, you would use

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
private DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator;
```

Comment: Thanks Yovi, i am now using Lombok, and it unfortunately does not work out-of-the-box with @Lazy. But all-in-all, it's a cool annotation, +1, thanks!